# Sort column in pandas, then sort another column while maintaining previous column sorted

Tags: python, pandas

So I have some data on lots of publicly traded stock. Each data row contains an id, a date, and some other information. Naturally, a stock might appear many times in the dataframe (i.e Google might have several entries that correspond to different dates at which the price was updated).

I want to be able to sort the ids, then for each sorted block, sort the dates.

NOTE: sorting is done in ascending order for the sake of the example.

```
    id        date price
0  123  2015/01/13     x
1  114  2017/02/15     y
2   12  2016/12/02     z
3  123  1996/04/26     w
4  114  2014/02/23     u
5  114  1995/05/25     v
```

**Sorting the ids gives:**

```
    id        date price
0   12  2016/12/02     z
1  123  2015/01/13     x
2  123  1996/04/26     w
3  114  2017/02/15     y
4  114  2014/02/23     u
5  114  1995/05/25     v
```

**Sorting the dates WHILE the ids are fixed gives:**

```
    id        date price
0   12  2016/12/02     z
1  123  1996/04/26     w
2  123  2015/01/13     x
3  114  1995/05/25     v
4  114  2014/02/23     u
5  114  2017/02/15     y
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you need [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'])
print (df)
    id       date price
2   12 2016-12-02     z
5  114 1995-05-25     v
4  114 2014-02-23     u
1  114 2017-02-15     y
3  123 1996-04-26     w
0  123 2015-01-13     x
```

Or if `id` column is `string`:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'])
print (df)
    id       date price
5  114 1995-05-25     v
4  114 2014-02-23     u
1  114 2017-02-15     y
2   12 2016-12-02     z
3  123 1996-04-26     w
0  123 2015-01-13     x
```

You can also sort one column descending and another ascending:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'], ascending=[False, True])
print (df)
    id       date price
3  123 1996-04-26     w
0  123 2015-01-13     x
2   12 2016-12-02     z
5  114 1995-05-25     v
4  114 2014-02-23     u
1  114 2017-02-15     y
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. I didn't realize you could sort dataframes by a group of column headers.

Comment: At first I did accept it but I was not allowed since I'm new. I guess now it works! Sorry :)

Comment: No problem. Now you can also upvote - if find some solution in StackOverflow helpful in future. Nice day!